# What is the difference between control flow graph & interprocedural control flow graph?

Tags: terminology, algorithm-analysis, programming-languages

I am doing research on control flow analysis on aspect oriented programs and I found in some papers an interprocedural approach for doing control flow analysis on others call graph or control flow graph. Is there a real difference between control flow graphs and interprocedural control flow graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CFG (Control Flow Graph): representing control flow for a single procedure
IPCFG (Inter-Procedural Control Flow Graph): representing control flow for a program

source: http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~weile/cs513x/4.ControlFlowAnalysis.pdf

Comment: Here's another, and IMHO more focussed and readable article https://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs252/2011sp/slides/Lec05-Interprocedural.pdf